# Update values in textbox if select combobox python

Tags: python, dataframe, tkinter

My textbox values are not updating whenever I select an option from a combobox. (no buttons involved)

Here's my coding:

```
def select_device(x):
        #self.tree.delete(*self.tree.get_children())
        for index, row in df3.loc[df3["MFG Device"].eq(comboExample1.get())].iterrows():
            cust_box.insert("end", list(row))

df3 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=["MFG Device", "Customer Name"])
df3.sort_values("MFG Device", inplace=True)
df3.drop_duplicates(subset="MFG Device", inplace=True)
df3["MFG Device"].tolist()
comboExample1 = ttk.Combobox(window, width=30, values=list(df3["MFG Device"].unique()), state="readonly")
comboExample1.current(o)
comboExample1.place(x=90, y=70)   
comboExample1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", select_device)
```

1. User select a Device in combobox
2. Display Customer Name in textbox
3. ---Repeat---
4. Textbox values will update whenever User selects a new device.

Wrong example:
[image: wrong]

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you verified that `select_device` is being called when you change the value of the combobox? Have you verified that `comboExample1.get()` is returning what you expect? Is `df3.log[df3]["MFG Device"].eq(...)` is returning what you expect? Perhaps your first step should be to break out that crazy long statement that controls the for loop into multiple lines so you can see the intermediate values.

Comment: Yes, the result is what I want.

Comment: If the result is what you expect, then the text must be inserted into the text widget. Something must be different than what you are reporting.

Comment: The text is correct but when User selects another value from the combobox, another line is added to the current one. I have updated the img above :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Have you done any debugging?

Comment: So, instead of "not updating", are you asking why the value is appending rather than replacing the current value?

Comment: Yes sorry if it's confusing, I also would like to know if there's any solution to "update the values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. If I understand what you wrote in the comments, you actually want to delete what is in the text widget and replace it with something new.

If that's the case, you just need to do exactly that - delete the old text and insert the new. You didn't tell us what `cust_box` is, so I'm going to assume it is a `Text` widget based on how you seem to be using it:

```
def select_device(x):
    cust_box.delete("1.0", "end")
    for index, row in df3.loc[df3["MFG Device"].eq(comboExample1.get())].iterrows():
        cust_box.insert("end", list(row))
```